# How to connect to ibm mq from runmqdnm command on SSL

Tags: ibm-mq

We are not able to connect to ibm mq from .NET code through runmqdnm command on SSL. Without SSL we are able to connect. With Queuemanager properties way we are able to connect.

```
 string command = $"runmqdnm -m {queueManager} -q {queueName} -s {yes} -a {assembly} -c {clss} ";

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQSERVER", serverVariable); // MQ server variable is set through environment
Keystore is also set as environment variable MQSSLKEYR E:\Certs\mq\key
```

I am not seeing any option to pass cipher spec and CertificateLabel.
while with Mq object we are able to pass like below.

```
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipher);
properties.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, certLabel);
```

Comment: You would need to use a CCDT.

Comment: As @JoshMc mentioned, you need a CCDT: "You cannot use MQSERVER to define an SSL channel ...", see [MQSERVER](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=variables-mqserver).

Comment: Thanks Josh and Daniel I will try with CCTD file. I think we need to set CertificateLabel property so I need to use MQCERTLABL this environment variable as per https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=variables-mqcertlabl.

Comment: You can also set the cert label in the CCDT CLNTCONN definition.  Also if you label the cert `ibmwebspheremq` plus the lowercase username that will be running the MQ program then there is no need to specify the label,  for example for USER1 the label would be `ibmwebspheremquser1`

Comment: I tried with CCTD file but I am getting this error amq8374s: ibm mq queue manager does not exist. when we are using CCTD file we don't pass server, port and channel all these details are from CCTD file and there is no exception in Event viewer this time.

Comment: I tried to pass MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB from code by setting Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable still the same above amq8374s exception. Is it possible to use runmqdnm on SSL. In docs it's was not specified at all.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc  do you have any idea on the exception amq8374s: ibm mq queue manager does not exist.  I tried multiple things like setting environment variables from code all of them are showing same error.

Comment: You mention SSLKEYR as pointing to the stub key, this is indicating it is a CMS (kdb) file.   I can't find it stated in the manual but believe runmqdnm is a Managed mode program, based on it stating it uses "MSDTC transaction coordination".  Managed mode programs use the windows key store not a kdb file.  Based on this I don't know if you can have it connect to a TLS channel.

Comment: I would suggest you look at the XMS.Net API using a async message listener.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. Most of our services are running on runmqdnm now for security reasons we need to use SSL. Somehow I need to make it work with SSL.

Comment: Look at this page amount connection property override for .NET, you would create a `runmqdnm.exe.config` file with a `<appSettings>` section pointed to a text file.   The text file would have things like `mqj.$SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` or `mqj.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`, it's not clear.   Your cert would go in the windows USER or SYSTEM key store.   Worth a try. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=languages-using-application-name-in-supported-programming

Comment: Sure @JoshMc. I will try this one.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. Runmqdnm is working fine with CCTD file. I got error because of queue manager name.

Comment: You should post a answer with details

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace MqTSR
{
    public class Runmqdnm : IMQObjectTrigger
    {
        static string queueManager = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queueManager"];
        static string queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queue"];
        static string certPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certPath"];
        static string cipher = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cipher"];
        static string message = "Hello IBM, this is a message";
        static string yes = "YES";
        static string assembly = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["assembly"];
        static string clss = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clss"];

        public static void TestConnection()
        {
            
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Testing MQ monitor");
            
                string command = $"runmqdnm -m {queueManager} -q {queueName} -s {yes} -a {assembly} -c {clss} ";
                
                ProcessStartInfo processinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c echo {message} | {command}");
                processinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                processinfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                using (Process process = Process.Start(processinfo))
                {
                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(output);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Testing MQ monitor success");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

      public void Execute(MQQueueManager qmgr, MQQueue queue, 
                         MQMessage message, string param)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("queuemeanager :{0}, queue:{1}", qmgr.Name, 
            queue.Name);
        }
   }
}
```

In App.config file add queueManager name, queue, assembly(.exe or dll), main class name (MqTSR.Runmqdnm).

In environment variables we need to pass MQCHLTAB, MQCHLLIB, MQSSLKEYR